# Filter data frame inside a function with a column argument

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to update a data frame column inside a function based on a filtered column.

```
#example dataframe
my.df = data.frame(A=1:10)

#define function to classify column passed as argument 2 based on argument 3
classify = function(df, col, threshold){
  df[df$col<threshold, 2] <- "low"
  df[df$col>=threshold, 2] <- "high"

  return(df)
}

#assign output to new.df
new.df = classify(my.df, A, 5)
```

I'd expect the new column to contain character values of 'low' or 'high', but instead they're all `<NA>`.

Comment: mutate(my.df, B = ifelse(A < 2, 'low', 'high')) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the string literal of the column name, `"A"`, and then inside the function receive the parameter with single or double bracket `[[...]]` indexing and not with `$`:

```
# example dataframe
my.df = data.frame(A=1:10)

# define function to classify column passed as argument 2 based on argument 3
classify = function(df, col, threshold){
  df[df[[col]] < threshold, 2] <- "low"
  df[df[[col]] >= threshold, 2] <- "high"

  return(df)
}

# assign output to new.df
new.df = classify(my.df, "A", 5)

new.df    
#     A   V2
# 1   1  low
# 2   2  low
# 3   3  low
# 4   4  low
# 5   5 high
# 6   6 high
# 7   7 high
# 8   8 high
# 9   9 high
# 10 10 high
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released 0.6.0) to do this.   The `enquo` takes the input argument and converts it to quosure which will be evaluated within the `mutate/group_by/filter` etc by unquoting (`UQ`)

```
library(dplyr)
classify <- function(df, col, threshold){
   col <- enquo(col)

   df %>%
       mutate(categ = ifelse(UQ(col) < threshold, "low", "high"))

}

classify(my.df, A, 5)
#    A categ
#1   1   low
#2   2   low
#3   3   low
#4   4   low
#5   5  high
#6   6  high
#7   7  high
#8   8  high
#9   9  high
#10 10  high
```